# How can I install themes in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, themes

How do I install themes in Lubuntu distro??

Please guide me on how to install [this theme](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/MacOS-X+Aqua+Theme?content=13548)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a general principle, you should acquaint yourself with the homepage of the distro you use and the respective wiki. You'll often find that your question is already answered there. For Lubuntu, the homepage is simply lubuntu.net and the wiki is here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu. There's a page on themes here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Theming

Answer (score 1):

It has a detailed guide, where are you stuck? Essentially, you download the files provided and you move them to themes and icons directories so ubuntu can recognize them as such. You can use a tool like Ubuntu Tweak to change to this theme.

Also be aware that this theme was submitted at **2004** so I am not sure it works on newer versions of linux.

Comment: That it is from 2004 is worrisome. Please try to find a more recent theme.

Comment: I tried it. Seems to work okay for gtk2 apps. Lubuntu doesn't have a lot of gtk3 apps. So OP may get away with using this theme!